# PhantomJS don't load mobile.twitter.com via Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, request, phantomjs

My configuration - *Selenium 2.44.0 + Python 3.4.2 + PhantomJS 2.0.0 (on Windows 7 x64)*.
I try to load https://mobile.twitter.com from Python program using PhantomJS WebDriver and I get error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\myprog\code.py", line 11, in <module>
    browser.get('https://mobile.twitter.com/')
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 171, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 417, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request)
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 455, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 473, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1202, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1177, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\http\client.py", line 1172, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\http\client.py", line 313, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\socket.py", line 371, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]
```

Code of my program:

```
import os, sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from random import randint
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\Program Files (x86)\PhantomJS\phantomjs.exe')

browser.get('https://mobile.twitter.com/')
sleep(randint(5,10))
browser.save_screenshot('out1.png')
g = open('C:\\Python\\Python342x64\\prog\\page.htm', 'a', encoding='utf8', errors='replace')
g.write(browser.page_source + '\n')
```

If I use Firefox instead of PhantomJS, everything work fine. (or if i load desktop version of twitter)
How I can fix this problem with PhantomJS?

Answer (score 1):

try to set user agent like:

> Android / Firefox 29: Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:29.0)
>   Gecko/29.0 Firefox/29.0

Comment: I've already tried different user agent settings, but it does not help. :(
I try:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"`
`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; Nexus 4 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19`
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3`

Comment: why you wanna absolutly use PJS in mobile version?

Comment: because it's lighter and faster than desktop version.

Comment: what you can't do using firefox?

Comment: I can't hide firefox window from screen, so i decide to use headless PhantomJS. And by the way  PhantomJS use only 15mb of RAM :)

Comment: PJS is a little browser, you can do a lot of operation and test but isn't a complete browser. you can have problem with page for plugin and particular implementation of many language.  WinError 10054 a is a network error. you can try to solve with a workaround, or switch to linux
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22252

Comment: I think my problem related with AJAX and with POST/GET requests, but I didn't found any information about this.

Comment: make a test. catch the exception and ignore it

Comment: How you think, what test and exception can I do?